# What are Olympus' best in-camera Jpg settings for facebook

Tags: image-quality, resolution, image-compression, facebook, olympus-omd

I usually shoot raw and make minimal in-camera post-processing with my O-M10 Mark II before exporting the photos to Facebook.

Did anyone figure out what are the best in-camera jpeg resolution and quality to export for Facebook?

I've been using the maximum resolution with super-fine quality, but wonder if it would make sense use less in-camera compression and a resolution closer to [what is recommended](https://www.facebook.com/help/266520536764594).

Did any of you tested the different possibilities and reached a conclusion about this?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend that you continue to use the highest resolution and the lowest compression settings.  Reason for this is so that you have a high-resolution copy just in case you want to make prints.  If you can shoot RAW+JEPG, then that would be a good solution.

When posting to social media, you don't need much more than about a 2MP image.  Anything larger will get reduced in resolution by Facebook not to mention that Facebook will also compress the heck out of it, too.  So since Facebook will apply their own edits to your images, it makes sense to have the least amount of compression.  The last thing you want to do is upload an image that has already been heavily compressed (all jpegs much be compressed by definition), just to have it further compressed by Facebook.  This can lead to color banding and other unwanted artifacts.

Most people who are concerned with their work being stolen from Facebook will limit the size of their images making them good enough for Facebook, but nothing else.  Therefore, limit the long edge of your images to about 1,200 pixels or less.

Comment: Technically, if you can get it below 100KB (yeah, yeah, I know that's tiny) facebook won't apply their own compression to it.

Comment: @MichaelClark AIUI even that no longer works. (Nor does uploading PNGs)